# Python Sort List, Skipping a Character

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of:

```
list = ["S9_1-", "S10_E1-17", "S25_1-21", "S3_1-", "S5_1-"]
```

if I do `print sorted(list)` I get:

```
['S10_E1-17', 'S25_1-21', 'S3_1-', 'S5_1-', 'S9_1-']
```

Is there a way I can ignore the letters, so it sorts it as:

```
['S3_1-', 'S5_1-', 'S9_1-', 'S10_E1-17', 'S25_1-21']
```

Comment: Firstly, Don't name variables `list`. Secondly are you sorting based on the digits before the `_`?

Comment: yeah, I want to sort based on digits before the _

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is the optional `key` argument in `sort`. You can use it to tell python to sort based on a function. In this case, that function can be expressed as follows:

```
def mykey(s):
    parts = s.split("_",1)
    importantPart = splits[0]
    number = int(importantPart[1:])  # remove the "S"
    return number
```

Of course, this can be expressed as a simple lambda:

```
lambda s: int(s.split("_",1)[0][1:])
```

And thus, you get the following:

```
In [21]: L = ['S10_E1-17', 'S25_1-21', 'S3_1-', 'S5_1-', 'S9_1-']

In [22]: sorted(L, key=lambda s: int(s.split("_",1)[0][1:]))
Out[22]: ['S3_1-', 'S5_1-', 'S9_1-', 'S10_E1-17', 'S25_1-21']
```

Answer (score 5):

```
seq = ["S9_1-", "S10_E1-17", "S25_1-21", "S3_1-", "S5_1-"] 
sorted_seq = sorted(seq, key=lambda item: int(item.split("_")[0][1:]))
assert sorted_seq == ['S3_1-', 'S5_1-', 'S9_1-', 'S10_E1-17', 'S25_1-21']
```